# How do I get the value from one method into another method in the same class?

Tags: ruby

How can I get the value from one method into another method in the same class so I can use it?

Example:

```
def initialize var1
  @var1 = var1
end

def method_a var2
  #Here how can I use var1 to add it to var1 to make a var2
  var2 = var1 + var1?
end

def method_b
  #display
  "#{@var1}, "#{var2}"
end
```

So I'd be making a second variable in `method_a` that was not initialized and then display it in `method_b`.

Comment: `@var1` is visible in all methods within the same class.

Comment: Yes but it's var2 that I need to create

Comment: If you want a value var2 defined as var1 + var1, it would make more sense to me to define a method called var2 which simply returns var1 + var1

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everybody.I got it.I was bogged down on gettting a second variable in method_b to display that I didn't realize I could just call method_a in the display method to get the value I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def method_a
  @var2 = @var1 + @var1 # or: @var2 = @var1*2
end

def method_b
  puts "#{@var1}, #{@var2}"
end
```

or someth like it:

```
class Foo
  def initialize var1
    @var1 = var1
    @var2 = method_a #or change this string to call method_a, so just: method_a and this return @var2 = @var1*2
  end
  def method_a
    @var1*2 #and there you should use variable @var2 = @var1 + @var1 (or @var1*2)
  end
  def method_b
    p "#{@var1}, #{@var2}"
  end
end


#=> boo = Foo.new(1)
#=> boo.method_b
#=> 1, 2
```